# Why does isOpen() function always return true?

Tags: database, qt, sqlite

In my constructor(qt 5.4.1 - windows 7):

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
db.open();

QSqlQuery q;
q.exec("create table authors(num integer, birthdate date)");
q.exec("insert into authors values('123', '2015-01-01')");
qDebug()<<"your info saved in db.";
```

Every things is okay until now but, later, I need to change my db and save some date permanently, so:

```
int Dialog::SaveInfosPermanent()
{

    QSqlDatabase::database().close();
    if ( QSqlDatabase::database().isOpen ()) {
        qDebug()<<"DB is open.";
        return 1;
    }

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("newDB.db");
    db.open();

    QSqlQuery q;
    q.exec("create table authors(num integer, birthdate date)");
    q.exec("insert into authors values('123', '2015-01-01')");
    qDebug()<<"your info saved in db.";

    return 0;
}
```

and output:

```
your info saved in db.
QSqlError("", "", "")
DB is open.
```

So what am I doing wrong? or there is better other ideas for changing db from memory to hard disk if user select a certain checkbox?

Comment: Are you aware `QSqlDatabase::database()` will, by default, also open DB connection? If it's not what you want then you have to specify the `open` parameter: `QSqlDatabase::database("QSQLITE", false).isOpen()`

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way to initialize db connection is to use connection name:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", connectionName);
```

With connection name you have some extra opportunity. 
Removing database from the list of database connections, find docs [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#removeDatabase):

```
QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(connectionName);
```

Get access to your database by name, find docs [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#database):

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database(connectionName);
```

In your case use `removeDatabase()` with connection name, but don't forget about scope of `db`. See example at link i attach.

You can also use db with the same name in both case, as [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase) says:

> Adds a database to the list of database connections using the driver
>   type and the connection name connectionName. If there already exists a
>   database connection called connectionName, that connection is removed.
>
> The database connection is referred to by connectionName. The newly
>   added database connection is returned.

Comment: So what what do you mean now? Do you mean i can't close the connection with default name now?

Comment: I mean that if you are not sure your connection close use safe way to do it